# Vuejs 2 moving items in array, doesn't retain array indexing

Tags: vue-component, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an array of elements that I supply for a vue component as a reactive data source (I'm inspecting the data with the vue chrome extension):

```
the view: [A,B,C,D,E]
the data: [A,B,C,D,E]
```

I want to move an item (D) to a new position (before B), so first I remove the element with `splice`, then reinsert it at the desired index:

```
the view: [A,D,B,C,E]   
the data: [A,B,C,D,E]
```

So when I hover over in the Chrome Vue inspector over the second component, in the view the third column gets highlighted. If I hover over the 3rd element in the data, in the view the 4th element get highlighted, and so on.

The view updates correctly, but I want underlying the data to follow it.
In the array the elements are objects.

I guess this is because they are passed as reference?

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found it, instead of splice I should use `set` and `remove` on the vue instance:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set

> You should avoid directly setting elements of a data-bound Array with
> indices, because those changes will not be picked up by Vue.js.
> Instead, use the augmented $set() method

Comment: You could make things easier for yourself by doing something like `[ { value: 'A' }, { value: 'B' } ]`. Also, make sure to set the `:key` properly in your `v-for` if you're using it. Writing this helps me understand a lot: https://jsfiddle.net/crswll/ewhewzkz/21/

Comment: Thanks, @BillCriswell ! Actually the objects I'm using are way more complex than the example I come up with (it has a lot of properties with sub-arrays, object, etc...)
The other thing is: `:key`-ing are not only important when using `v-for` with `<transition>`? Or at least that's what I read somewhere, and that is what the console error messages were complaining about.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as well, what happened was I didn't use unique `key` values for each vue object in the array. I used the index in the array as the key. So when items were resorted, some of the data would be binded to different items because keys were swapped.

What I used was a `Date.now()` function to initialize a UUID to set for each key

---

So for instance, say we had the key set to the index of the array

```
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4] - The keys
[A0,B0,C0,D0,E0] - The array of objects
[A1,B1,C1,D1,E1] - The data attribute inside each of the objects in array
```

So [A0] has a key of [0], and data attribute of [A1].
Say we swap [A0] and [B0]

```
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4] - the key
[B0,A0,C0,D0,E0] - the array of objects
[A1,B1,C1,D1,E1] - the data attribute assigned to each object in array
```

Now [A0] is binded to the data attribute of [B1], because
[B1] is binded to the key of [1] and A[0] key is [1]

This is never what you want, so you want to make each key unique instead. A common way of doing this is using a `Date.now()` method upon data initialization, or a create a `UUID`

---

### In Summary

Example in Vue for creating a unique UUID for each object when using vue methods

```
    methods: {
      _addGroup: function() {
        let result = {
          sortId: this.wizardGroups.length + 1,
          text: 'Hello world'
          uuid: Date.now(),
        };
        this.wizardGroups.push(result);
      }
```

Assign that value to the key during `v-for` iteration

```
<child-component
  v-for="wizardGroup in wizardGroups"
  :key="wizardGroup.uuid">
</child-component>
```